# division of two very large numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I want to calculate `(a+b)/pow(2,s)`.

```
-10^10 ≤ s ≤ 10^10
1 ≤ a, b ≤ 10^9
```

But even if I store the result in `long long` it gives 0. How can I calculate the result given that the answer lies in the range of `long`?

Comment: use floats instead, or a bignum library.

Comment: What exactly are you using numbers this large for?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Aside: `pow` is for *floating point* exponentiation; you shouldn't use it when you are doing integer calculations.

Comment: The 10 ^10:th power of 2 is so large that Wolfram Alpha chokes on it. The 10^9:th power is ~4.65 * 10 ^ 301029995, so for all practical purpose, the result *is* 0. (The number of atoms in the universe is estimated to be 10 ^ 80.)

Comment: Are you sure it's `-10^10 ≤ s ≤ 10^10` and not `-10^10 ≤ pow(2,s) ≤ 10^10`?

Comment: Also, can you show your code and sample inputs?

Comment: Neither using a wider representation for the result nor automatic conversion to `double` (type of `pow()`) prevents loss of bits from `a+b` (which will stay in the range of "32 bit" integers _given the range quoted for `a` and `b`_).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need division for this... dividing by a power of two is just a right-shift.

Comment: @Ishan: your question uses `long long`, so that's no concern.

Comment: With float (or double) you can "shift" by adjusting the exponent. See the ldexp function.

Comment: i dint get it pls elaborate

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was pointless. This one here is the best way, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a good [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library, e.g. [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Bignum operations are a difficult algorithmic issue (there are several books on the subject, and you can still earn a PhD to improve them). So don't try to reinvent them yourself (if you want them to be more efficient than the slow naive algorithms everyone learned at elementary school, you'll need many years of hard work) but use an existing bignum library.

Perhaps you have some [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you don't need to compute that in fact. (You did not motivate your question enough).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::bitset<log2(10^9)>` manually calculate the sum and then call `operator>>=( s )` on result and obtain long by `std:bitset::to_ulong()`

Comment: and the answer is going to be zero in many cases, ulong cannot represent x/(2^10^10)

Comment: @pm "given that the answer lies in the range of long"

Comment: the answer does not lie in the range of long for the given input constaints. 2 * 10^9 / pow(2,10^10)  is not a long

Comment: @pm100 it is in the range for given requirements. I am not going to question them.

Comment: no its not - many of the answers in the range are way off the charts

Comment: @pm100 then there is something wrong, maybe range is wrong maybe that it fits long, maybe when it does not fit long he does not care. What do you want from me? Question OP ask him to fix his requirements, then I will fix my answer.

Comment: The answer might lie in the range for long when the inputs are larger

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost cpp_int](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html), it is easiest way.